# Yii: How to redirect and go to a specific element on page?

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to redirect and go to a specific element on the new page like this:

```
http://192.168.0.49/x/y/index.php/admin/user/update/id/3#certificate

$this->redirect(array('update', 'id' => $certificate->user_id));
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't be done using `redirect`.
A work around would be

```
$url = Yii::app()->createUrl('update', array('id' => $certificate->user_id, '#' => "certificate"));
$this->redirect($url);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create the url without the fragment part and then append it manually:

```
$url = Yii::app()->createUrl('update', ['id' => $certificate->user_id]);
$url .= "#certificate";

$this->redirect($url);
```

This code works in a manner that is immediately obvious when reading the code. Apart from that there is also the Yii-specific solution: `CUrlManager` (the component responsible for building URLs) also [recognizes `#` as a parameter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#createUrl-detail). So you can write:

```
$url = Yii::app()->createUrl(
    'update',
    ['id' => $certificate->user_id, '#' => 'certificate']
);
```